# How to avoid child block elements to be wrapped?

Tags: css, html

I have a container div `.parent` with a fixed width `500px` which contains a lot of child divs `.child`.

The problem is that the child divs are getting auto wrapped, in my case i want them to continue in one line even if they'll be hidden and after that i'll add custom buttons to horizontally scroll the `.parent` div.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/egohi3

How to achieve that with keeping the floating?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the parent element have `white-space:nowrap` and the child elements to be `display:inline-block` (instead of floating). Here is a modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/7we5q/

Answer (score 1):

@Phrogz's answer will work. You could also add *another* wrapper `<div>` inside "parent" and give it both "overflow: hidden" and a huge width (like "width: 100000px;").